# Is it right to say 'You destiny is in your hand'?

Tags: grammar, difference

Is it right to say 'You destiny is in your hand'?
Or it's better to say 'Your destiny is in your hands?

Comment: *Your hands* is the idiom. *Your hand* doesn't make sense.

Comment: As an aside, I have a friend who only has one hand, and he always uses the plural form when saying things like, "I'm going to wash my hands", even though he is only going to wash one hand :)

Answer (score 2):

*in your hands* is a set phrase in this context. Makes sense since it is unlikely you do many important things with only one hand.
So:

> Your destiny is **in your hands.**

Or a famous insurance company slogan:

> "You are **in good hands** with ..."